# Notifying a control that another control has a state change

Tags: notifications, c++builder, delegation

I am using C++Builder Enterprise and need some ideas.

I have a Form with a bunch of `TButton` and `TSpeedButton` controls on it.  What I want to have happen is that, when a given button is pressed, I want to disable it and several others, while enabling several other buttons, i.e. state changes.

The issue is that I am duplicating the enable/disable code in a bunch of places.  I've thought about somehow using the `TNotifyEvent` delegation to alert the buttons of a state change, but I don't think that delegation technique will work in this situation. I want to avoid creating a bunch of sub-classes of `TButton`/`TSpeedButton`.

I also would like to try to use techniques that are available from the VCL, as in each component carries an observer list and wonder if I could leverage that somehow.

Comment: For the most part, the VCL does not have an observer system (some classes do, but UI controls do not, well not for what you want anyway), so you would have to implement that manually. I think an easier solution would be to add a `TActionManager` to the Form, create 2 actions in it, and then assign them to the `Action` property of the buttons as needed.  Then, whenever a button is clicked, have its `OnClick` event simply set the `Sender`'s `Action.Enabled=false` and set the other `Action.Enabled=true`. The associated buttons will all be updated automatically.

Comment: Alternatively you can simply define a `bool` variable to hold your state, and then use the `TApplication(Events)::OnIdle` event, or a `TAction::OnUpdate` event, to enable/disable your buttons as needed based on the current value of that variable.

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you for the response.  Yep that seems to be the way to go, as I've spent way too much time on these pesky button states.  However, use of the OnIdle event is an interesting thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My 2 cents worth..

I have done a proof of concept for your problem, would need a lot more work but I think it is doable and should do what you want.

I will do more work on it and post if there is interest.

To find all controls of a class type on a form

--- TControlAgent->FindTControl(this, "TButton");

I added 4 buttons on a form, added code bellow to button1 click event,

TControlAgent->SetControlProperty("Enabled", "TButton", false, true, "Button3");

in this case, want controls with Enabled property whose class name is TButton, state = true or false, execute the action but but exclude control named TButton3

There result was all TButtons on the form were set to disable except for button 3

(note: the exclude option would be a lookup list of controls to be excluded from any action or be able to set a state that is not the state eg Enabled = !true or !false )

In the click event of button3 I placed the following code;

TControlAgent->SetControlProperty("Enabled", "TButton", true, true, "");

The result of this is to re-enable all the controls, this is just an idea but with with the extra work it could be possible to execute any action on any control from a single parent form for any form in a collection of forms.

I also think it could be possible to fire events, just a crazy idea...

.h file using berlin 10.1

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef TControlAgentH
#define TControlAgentH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <System.TypInfo.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class PACKAGE TControlAgent : public TComponent
{
private:
    std::vector<TControl*> FControls;
protected:
public:
  std::vector<UnicodeString> excludeControlNames;
    __fastcall TControlAgent(TComponent* Owner);
    TControl * __fastcall GetControl(TControl* ctrl, UnicodeString property);
    void __fastcall FindTControl(TForm *f, UnicodeString className);
  TControl* __fastcall SetControlProperty(UnicodeString property, UnicodeString className, bool state, bool exec, UnicodeString excludeControlName   );
__published:
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

.cpp file

```
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>

#pragma hdrstop

#include "TControlAgent.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ValidCtrCheck is used to assure that the components created do not have
// any pure virtual functions.
//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// component to act as agent for other components derived from TControl
//
//  Components have properties and events, is it possible to get all TControls into a vector
//  then be able to get a property of a component then fire an event or carry out an action
//  on the component!!!!
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
static inline void ValidCtrCheck(TControlAgent *)
{
    new TControlAgent(NULL);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TControlAgent::TControlAgent(TComponent* Owner)
    : TComponent(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TControlAgent::FindTControl(TForm *f, UnicodeString className)
    {
    FControls.clear();

    for(int i = 0; i < f->ControlCount; i++)
        {
        if(f->Controls[i]->ClassName() == className)  //control classes that to set as a group
            FControls.push_back(f->Controls[i]);
        }
    //note:  could have a function that appends other class names
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TControl* __fastcall TControlAgent::SetControlProperty(UnicodeString property, UnicodeString className, bool state, bool exec, UnicodeString excludeControlName  )
    {
    PPropInfo propinfo;
    for(int i = 0; i < FControls.size(); i++)
        {
        if(FControls[i]->ClassName() == className)
            {
            propinfo = GetPropInfo(FControls[i], property);
            if (!propinfo)
                continue;
            if(exec && FControls[i]->Name != excludeControlName )
                {
                if(property == "Enabled")
                    FControls[i]->Enabled = state;
                }
            }

        }

    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace Tcontrolagent
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
        TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TControlAgent)};
        RegisterComponents(L"SQLite", classes, 0);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you OldTimer...wow I didn't get you anything!  Haha.  Well I'm officially in the old timers league as well.  Wrote my first "Basic" program in 1984.  Anyway, this looks pretty dang cool, I need to put it in my enviro and see if it's something to integrate into my program.  But at first look I like the idea.  Remy's suggestion is also good, using the TActionManager can be useful in these circumstances and doesn't really require a lot of coding.  Anyway again thank you and lemme play around with the idea, I'll certainly respond as soon as I'm able.

Comment: Yep it works for sure!  So I'll try to use it in my main project and see if fits in with my logic.  Thank you again for the insight, and a little education of the VCL to boot.

Comment: @pjackson seems like we started about the same time me, 1982 :)

Comment: Another thought would be to create a list of excluded controls, i.e. buttons, using a TVarRec in the SetControlProperty method for the excluded names.  Then modify the inner loop to go through that list setting the property accordingly.  Using a variadic argument set excludes the use of the __fastcall macro.

Comment: @pjackson  the potential for this is huge, the code is based on other components I have written, the thing about this idea is that the component would need only be placed on the main form and as long as you have other forms defined be they created at run time or dynamically created in your app, access to any control from the main form would be achievable for any form in your app. I have lots of ideas around this, will work on it.

Comment: Yep, I have already created components (more than 10 years ago) that allows inclusion and exclusion of edit controls like text boxes, tree views, combo boxes etc. components also manage forms comms between forms.  happy that you like the idea and I have opened your mind to other possibilities.

Comment: So another comment on TControlAgent.  The reason I  want to do some type of variadic parameter list is because doing as is is just about like assigning each button itself, ie hard coding each in the various OnClick methods.  Btw, I love this idea!  So, if we used some kind of list for the exclusions then it would be easy enough to just use the TControlAgent in only a few places instead of for each of button click.  Also by maybe using a Task we could get rid of most of the method calls altogether and and just set a "control" variable to push the actions out.

Comment: I dunno just thinking out loud right now and not really thinking it through so this may be mumbling, I am at work in a meeting and it is boring as all get out!  So don't take all this is heart just yet, I have yet to really explore all the details, although I did implement last night and it did work as you intended.  The last thing is I need to get on with my project so I don't want to spend too much time as I have much much more to do.. Again thank you for your insights

Comment: Agree with your comment, the idea of the TControlAgent is to have it act a a surrogate for the controls you want, what you have said is correct in that calling the method on the click event of each button is no better than hard coding what you want to achieve. This could be overcome by replacing std::vector<TControl*> FControls; with something like a struct which contains TControl* ctrl; std::vector<TControl*> excludes; bool FireStateChange;  the TControla Agent could then look at the TControl, look at excluded controls for the specific TControl and fire an event handler, like OnStateChange,

Comment: for each control that has had its state changed using other methodes in the TControlAgent, you could also have a vector of controls to be excluded a group by container, i.e. TPanel,  I will try and implement these today if I can.

Comment: Yep that sounds exactly like where I'm heading.  Oldtimer, if I may call you that - haha - you really don't need to write the code that is unless you're just having fun doing it.  I was gonna further expand on your code and implement some changes too.  That said, I would love to see where you end up with it all.  And I really appreciate your discussions with me - and help of course.

Comment: I think you're right in saying that this is huge, personally I could use this all the time in my different projects and while I'm sure it's not reinventing the wheel, I haven't seen an easier way to do this.  I guess that's what I was alluding to with Remy, i.e. using a mediator pattern, like this, and having it delegate to each component to update itself based on some control property.  Yep I love this kinda stuff!

Comment: I have done some more work on the component, have implemented an event that handles an OnChange of property value which works ok in  it's infant stage,much more work needed though as there is lots of dynamic scenarios that need to be factored, also implemented an exclude vector as part of a symbiotic association of a primary control, the idea of this is that a tbutton can control the enabled state of any number of other tbuttons on a form or panel (container) group,. when I have something I am happy with, I will post answer.

Comment: Yep, you can call me Oldtimer but, never late for diner:) haha.  as an fyi, I have written about 45 non visual and visual components, some of these identify all components on a container, form and fill contents as a record from a database table and handles the data entry order as well as any validation based on custom properties and events of sub classed components.  will look at replacing event handlers of controls and delegate to the TControlAGent of course these are all ideas that need work to test the theory that they will work out.

Comment: Another FYI, I did select that you Answered from your earlier post!

Answer (score 0):

**** UPDATED *****
Progress of TControlAgent

Obviously still work in progress but this code works, create a form with a TPanel, to this add 6 TButtons

Add a TControl Agent, set the OnButtonClick event as per Form code bellow

TControlAgent code
.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef TControlAgentH
#define TControlAgentH
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.SysUtils.hpp>
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <System.TypInfo.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class TControls;
class TControlGroup;

typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TControlAgentOnClick)(System::TObject *Sender, TControls *ctrl);
typedef void __fastcall (__closure *TButtonClickEvent)(System::TObject *Sender);
enum action {aEnabled, aOnClick, aChange};
enum tcontrols {tbutton, tedit, tcombo, tcheckbox};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class PACKAGE TControlAgent : public TComponent
{
private:
    std::vector<TControls*> FControls;
    std::vector<TControlGroup*> FControlGroups;

    TControlAgentOnClick FClickSupliment;
    TButtonClickEvent FOnButtonClick;
    bool FButtonClickRedirect;

protected:

public:
    std::vector<UnicodeString> excludeControlNames;  // not implemented yet
    std::vector<TControlGroup*> __fastcall Groups();
    std::vector<TControls*> __fastcall Controls(int GroupIndex);
    __fastcall TControlAgent(TComponent* Owner);
    TControl * __fastcall GetControl(TControl* ctrl, UnicodeString property);
    void __fastcall FindTControl(TForm *f, UnicodeString className);
    void __fastcall FindTControl(TPanel *p, UnicodeString GroupName, bool ClearIfControlsExists);
    void __fastcall SetControlProperty(TControl *ctrl, bool state, int Action);
    int __fastcall GetGroup(String name);
    void __fastcall SetControlClickEvent(String ClassName, String GroupName, String ExcludeGroup, int tControlType);
    void __fastcall SetButtonPropValue(TButton* b, String Property, String Value, bool v);
    int __fastcall AddTControl(TControl* c, String Group);
    void __fastcall SetButtonPropValue(String Group, String ExcludeGroup,int TControlType,String Property,String GroupValue,bool GroupV,String excludeGroupValue,bool excludeGroupV);


__published:
    __property bool TButtonClick = {read = FButtonClickRedirect, write = FButtonClickRedirect };
    __property TControlAgentOnClick OnClickSuppliment={read=FClickSupliment, write=FClickSupliment};
    __property TButtonClickEvent OnButtonClick = {read = FOnButtonClick, write = FOnButtonClick };
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TControlGroup
    {
    public:
        UnicodeString GroupName;
        std::vector<TControls*> GroupControls;
        __fastcall TControlGroup();
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TControls
    {
    public:
        TControl* ctrl;
        bool WantButtonOnClick;
        bool WantControlOnChange;
        bool FireStateChange;
        bool WantOnClickSupliment;
        bool state;
        __fastcall TControls();
    };

#endif
```

.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>

#pragma hdrstop

#include "TControlAgent.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ValidCtrCheck is used to assure that the components created do not have
// any pure virtual functions.
//
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
// component to act as agent for other components derived from TControl
//
//  Components have properties and events, is it possible to get all TControls into a vector
//  then be able to get a property of a component then fire an event or carry out an action
//  on the component!!!!
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct IsCtrlGroup {
    String _name;

    IsCtrlGroup(String name) : _name(name)
        {
        }

    bool operator()(const TControlGroup * item) const
        {
        return (item->GroupName == _name);
        }
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct IsClassName {
    String _name;

    IsClassName(String name) : _name(name)
        {
        }

    bool operator()(const TControl * item) const
        {
        return (item->ClassName() == _name);
        }
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct IsCtrl {
    TControl* _ctrl;

    IsCtrl(TControl* ctrl) : _ctrl(ctrl) {
    }

    bool operator()(const TControls * item) const {
        return (item->ctrl->Name == _ctrl->Name);
    }
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

static inline void ValidCtrCheck(TControlAgent *)
{
    new TControlAgent(NULL);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TControlAgent::TControlAgent(TComponent* Owner)
    : TComponent(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TControlAgent::FindTControl(TForm *f, UnicodeString className)
    {
    FControls.clear();
    TControls* ctrl;

    for(int i = 0; i < f->ControlCount; i++)
        {
        if(f->Controls[i]->ClassName() == className)  //control classes that to set as a group
            {
            TControls* ctrl = new TControls();
            ctrl->ctrl = f->Controls[i];
            ctrl->FireStateChange = false;
            ctrl->WantOnClickSupliment = false;
            FControls.push_back(ctrl);
            }
        }
        //note:  could have a function that appends other class names
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TControlAgent::FindTControl(TPanel *p, UnicodeString GroupName, bool ClearIfControlsExists)
    {
    /*
    group vector[]
        --> controlsindex  vector[index]

    */
    TControlGroup* g;
    TControls* ctrl;

    int i = -1;
    int group_index = -1, controls_index = -1;

    // check if group name exists in group vector
    group_index = GetGroup(GroupName);

    //clear controls vector if exists, controls will not exist if group does not exist...
    if(ClearIfControlsExists && group_index > 0)
        FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls.clear();

    // if group does not exist, push new group onto vector
    if(group_index == -1)
        {
        g = new TControlGroup();
        g->GroupName = GroupName;
        FControlGroups.push_back(g);
        group_index = GetGroup(GroupName);
        }

    //group must bnow exist
    for(i = 0; i < p->ControlCount; i++)
        {
        TControls* ctrl = new TControls();
        ctrl->ctrl = p->Controls[i];
        FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls.push_back(ctrl);
        controls_index = FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls.size() -1;
        FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls[controls_index]->ctrl = p->Controls[i];
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int __fastcall TControlAgent::AddTControl(TControl* c, String Group)
    {
    int  index;
    TControlGroup* g;

    int group_index = GetGroup(Group);
    if(group_index == -1)
        {
        g = new TControlGroup();
    g->GroupName = Group;
        FControlGroups.push_back(g);
        group_index = GetGroup(Group);
        }

    TControls* ctrl = new TControls();
    ctrl->ctrl = c;
    FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls.push_back(ctrl);
    index = FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls.size()-1;
    return(index);

    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TControlAgent::SetControlClickEvent(String ClassName, String GroupName, String ExcludeGroup, int tControlType)
    {
    int group_index = GetGroup(GroupName);

    for(int i = 0; i < FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls.size(); i++)
        {
        if(FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls[i]->ctrl->ClassName() == ClassName)
            {
            switch(tControlType)
                {
                case tbutton:
                    dynamic_cast<TButton*>(FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls[i]->ctrl)->OnClick = FOnButtonClick;
                    break;
                case tedit:
                    break;
                case tcombo:
                    break;
                case tcheckbox:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
std::vector<TControlGroup*> __fastcall TControlAgent::Groups()
    {
    return(FControlGroups);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
std::vector<TControls*> __fastcall TControlAgent::Controls(int GroupIndex)
    {
    return(FControlGroups[GroupIndex]->GroupControls);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int __fastcall TControlAgent::GetGroup(String name)
    {
    int group_index =-1;
    std::vector<TControlGroup*>::iterator found = std::find_if(FControlGroups.begin(), FControlGroups.end(), IsCtrlGroup(name));
    if(found != FControlGroups.end())
         group_index =  std::distance(FControlGroups.begin(), found);
    return(group_index);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TControlAgent::SetButtonPropValue(TButton* b, String Property, String Value, bool v)
    {
    PPropInfo propinfo;
    propinfo = GetPropInfo(b, Property);
    if (!propinfo)
        return;

    if(Value.IsEmpty())
        SetPropValue(b, propinfo, v);
    else
        SetPropValue(b, propinfo, Value);

    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TControlAgent::SetButtonPropValue(String Group,
                                                                                                    String ExcludeGroup,
                                                                                                    int TControlType,
                                                                                                    String Property,
                                                                                                    String GroupValue,
                                                                                                    bool GroupV,
                                                                                                    String excludeGroupValue,
                                                                                                    bool excludeGroupV)
    {
    // Group can hold all TControls on a form
    // ExcludeGroup contains TControls that will be excluded from an action on the Group controls
    // Group is an existing group of TControls found on a container
    // ExcludGroup is a group that can be found on a container or added to a Group
    //  then parsed to this method in ExcludeGroup param

    int i;
    PPropInfo propinfo;
    TControl *c;
    int group_index = GetGroup(Group);
    int exclude_Group_index = GetGroup(ExcludeGroup);
    TControl* ctrl;
    for(i = 0; i < FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls.size(); i++)
        {
        c = FControlGroups[group_index]->GroupControls[i]->ctrl;
        //check if TControl is to be excluded

        std::vector<TControls*>::iterator found = std::find_if(FControlGroups[exclude_Group_index]->GroupControls.begin(),
                                                                                                                             FControlGroups[exclude_Group_index]->GroupControls.end(),
                                                                                                                             IsCtrl(c));

        // if found, control is in the exclude list so continue, do not apply
        // property value change
        if(found != FControlGroups[exclude_Group_index]->GroupControls.end())
            {
            c = (*found)->ctrl;
            //set property value for exclude group controls
            propinfo = GetPropInfo(c, Property);
            if(propinfo)
                {
                if(excludeGroupValue.IsEmpty())
                    SetPropValue(c, propinfo, excludeGroupV);
                else
                    SetPropValue(c, propinfo, excludeGroupValue);
                }

            continue;
            }

        //if it gets here, c is not in exclude list
        propinfo = GetPropInfo(c, Property);
        if (!propinfo)
            return;


        if(GroupValue.IsEmpty())
            SetPropValue(c, propinfo, GroupV);
        else
            SetPropValue(c, propinfo, GroupValue);

        }

    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace Tcontrolagent
{
    void __fastcall PACKAGE Register()
    {
        TComponentClass classes[1] = {__classid(TControlAgent)};
        RegisterComponents(L"SQLite", classes, 0);
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TControls::TControls(){}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TControlGroup::TControlGroup(){}
```

Form Code

.cpp

Form has a TPanel with 6 TButtons placed on it

@run time TButton3 is disabled

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "frmTControlTest.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma link "TControlAgent"
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm3 *Form3;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm3::TForm3(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
    {
    int i;
    std::vector<TControls*> group_controls;
    //get ALL controls on a container
    ControlAgent1->FindTControl(p, "Group1", true);
    //create the exclude (for want of a better name) groups
    /*
    add
    edit
    save
    delete
    cancel
    exit
    */
    ControlAgent1->AddTControl(bnSave, "Group2");
    ControlAgent1->AddTControl(bnCancel, "Group2");

    ControlAgent1->AddTControl(bnAdd, "Group3");
    ControlAgent1->AddTControl(bnEdit, "Group3");
    ControlAgent1->AddTControl(bnDelete, "Group3");
    ControlAgent1->AddTControl(bnExit, "Group3");


    i = ControlAgent1->GetGroup("Group1");

    group_controls = ControlAgent1->Controls(i);

    ControlAgent1->SetControlClickEvent("TButton", "Group1", "", tbutton);

    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm3::ControlAgent1ButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
    {
    TButton* b;
    if((b = dynamic_cast<TButton*>(Sender)) == bnAdd )
        ControlAgent1->SetButtonPropValue("Group1", "Group2", tbutton, "Enabled", "", false, "", true);
    if((b = dynamic_cast<TButton*>(Sender)) == bnCancel )
        ControlAgent1->SetButtonPropValue("Group1", "Group3", tbutton, "Enabled", "", false, "", true);
    if((b = dynamic_cast<TButton*>(Sender)) == bnSave )
        {
        ControlAgent1->SetButtonPropValue("Group1", "Group3", tbutton, "Enabled", "", false, "", true);
    //Do Stuff
        }


    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That's quite a bit of coding there OldTimer!  It looks great!  You should throw it up on git  when you're finished and make it available to all. Thank you for the encouragement too!

Comment: Is a bit of code but still just a tiny amount compared to the possibilities the component has, unfortunately I do not have a git account and unlikely to get one, too old, the component is just a statement of what can be done, realistically, it could be possible to reassign click events based on user response to button presses, edit box content, yada yada yada I am sure there are lots of coders that could take what I have done and expand on it much better than what I can, somebody like remy who has helped me heaps over the years.  It would be nice if there were a section on Stack Overflow

Comment: Continued from last comment: for a section that members could post code projects (approved by moderator of course) so that others can benefit.

Comment: Yeah, that would be super helpful and nice! And oh yeah, Remy has helped me out on several very much needed occasions.  Thank you Remy.  In any event, I may grab your code at some point later and expand on it, put it out there somewhere maybe on my up and coming website, which has been up and coming for several years now.  Of course with your permission and all the "originally written by" tags, etc.  Anyway it is a great idea and I think it should be expanded upon and packaged up for use.  For now I have to grind out a small Tip pool cakc program for a customer.  Hope to talk again soon sir!

Comment: You are welcome to grab and use, I am and will test out a few more ideas I have.  One thing to remember is that you could have more than one control agent in your app and send / set properties and values across all TForms by groups of TControls

Comment: Yeah man, I like it.  When I get back to my main project in a couple weeks, I will rally look at it and will likely use the code.  Feel free to email too, my email should be public?  If not lemme know and I put it here.

Comment: Cheers, I cannot see an email address for you.

Comment: So I'm not super up on stackoverflow, is my email not public?  Anyway it jwareservices@gmail.com